# Anyone knows how to define an interface in Jpad?

Tags: jpad

Anyone knows how to define an interface in Jpad? Code like this will result in an "interface not allowed here" error.

```
interface Try{
    boolean validate(String s);
}

class ValidateString implements Try{
    boolean validate(String s) {return true; }
}

ValidateString val = new ValidateString();
Dump(val.validate("hi"));
```

Answer (score 0):

JPad automatically wraps your code in a RunnContainer class as well as any 'loose' code in a static main method if you don't specify one. So the code provided was trying to stick a Class and Interface into the main method. Specifying the main resolves the issue. After running a jpad script you can view the "File" tab to show the results of how JPad wrapped it.

```
 public static void main(String args[]) {
    ValidateString val = new ValidateString();
    Dump(val.validate("hi"));
}

public static class ValidateString implements Try{
    public boolean validate(String s) {return true; }
}

interface Try{
    boolean validate(String s);
}
```

Comment: Please explain what you have done to resolve the problem, instead of just writing some code.